# Handle php which get ajax json request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

Suppose I run this ajax -

```
$.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data :{test : 123}, //updated due to the approved answer
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

and I want to get its json content in - `index.php` and `alert` its `test` value (mean get - `123`) ,

I tried this -

**index.php-**

```
<?php
    $json = $_POST["test"];
    echo '<script>';
    echo 'alert('+$json+');';
    echo '</script>';
?>
```

but nothing was alerted .

How to handle it correctly ?

**Update:**

Following @JayBlanchard comment,

does `$json = $_POST["test"]` is really get the `test` value ?

The `alert` isn't important for me , I just want to ensure whether it's parsed correctly in the PHP side , **mean get the `123` back to the client side**  .

Comment: The PHP is happening on the server-side and cannot throw a JavaScript `alert()` back. You could do it in the AJAX callback though.

Comment: FYI php's string concatenation character is the period: `.` not `+`

Comment: Is not clear if you need a JSON response from the server ora a text response to receive. if you need to receive a complex data  structure or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the results from your php in your JavaScript callback. So you could do this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data :{text : 123},
    dataType: 'json',
    complete: function(data){
        console.log(data.responseText) //(not sure why responseText is necessary)
    }
});
```

Your php would be something like:

```
<?php
$json = $_POST["text"];
echo $json;
?>
```

Comment: I tried it but it `alert` `[object]Object]` instead of `123` .

Comment: Ah, I see the problem. You need to have the names of the variables identical. So you have `data: {text: 123}` so in PHP you should access `$_POST["text"]`

Answer (score 0):

You would do this simply in the `success` callback:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {text : 123},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
       alert(data.test);
    }
});
```

And your `index.php`:

```
<?php
    echo json_encode(array('test' => $_POST['test']));
?>
```

Comment: He needs his PHP script to then return the JSON.

Comment: @silkfire : it doesn't `alert` nothing for me .

Comment: @URL87 Do you get any errors? Can you check in the Developer Tools of your browser what response you're getting from the server?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a javascript function to handle response:

```
var handle_response = function(data_from_server, StatusText, jqxhr) {
    // check http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for StatusText and jqxhr meaning.
    alert(data_from_server);
}
```

Then you call your ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "index.php",
    type: 'POST',
    data :{text : 123},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: handle_response
});
```

your php will be something like

```
<?php
    $json = json_decode($_POST["text"]);  // not sure about dataType: 'json'

    echo "this is coming from php on server ";
?>
```

if you want to execute some script created from the server check on jquery manual how to do it safely.

Comment: it doesn't `alert` nothing .

Comment: We gave you all the same solution more or less :) so just tweak it till it works. use console.debug till you notice what is wrong. To check what you are sending use "var_dump($_POST);" in php and see the output. to see the output , open firefox console and right click to check "register header and body of the response" or whatever it is called. Then from the ajax call you see what the server output. Hope it helps.